# Sitecore Express Migration Tool skipping users and security group

Tags: security, user-profile, express-migration-tool

Sitecore Express Migration Tool 3.0 upgrade to Sitecore 9.0 is skipping users and security group. the security checkbox was checked.

any idea what could be causing this?

below is the logs

```
[  1] 08:32:44.540 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: ''.
[  1] 08:32:44.888 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'basic_parameters_step'.
[  1] 08:33:00.189 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'basic_parameters_step'.
[  1] 08:33:00.390 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'instance_parameters'.
[  1] 08:36:47.419 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'instance_parameters'.
[  1] 08:36:49.444 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'wizard_population_step'.
[  1] 08:36:51.790 INFO  [Population step] Population started.
[ 11] 08:36:51.843 WARN  [Population step] Database cleanup triggered. Note, that could lead to lost information about already processed items.
[ 11] 08:36:53.511 WARN  [PopulationManager] Population step skipped, because it's disabled: Core database
[ 11] 08:36:53.520 WARN  [PopulationManager] Population step skipped, because it's disabled: Master database
[ 11] 08:36:53.526 WARN  [PopulationManager] Population step skipped, because it's disabled: Locations
[  1] 08:36:53.526 INFO  [Population step] Population finished.
[  1] 08:36:58.883 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'wizard_population_step'.
[  1] 08:36:58.912 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'select_core_db_items'.
[  1] 08:37:01.171 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the previous step. Current step key: 'select_core_db_items'.
[  1] 08:37:01.197 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the previous step. Current step key: 'wizard_population_step'.
[  1] 08:37:01.718 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the previous step. Current step key: 'wizard_population_step'.
[  1] 08:37:01.733 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the previous step. Current step key: 'instance_parameters'.
[  1] 08:37:02.325 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the previous step. Current step key: 'instance_parameters'.
[  1] 08:37:02.396 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the previous step. Current step key: 'basic_parameters_step'.
[  1] 08:37:04.340 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'basic_parameters_step'.
[  1] 08:37:04.410 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'instance_parameters'.
[  1] 08:37:06.275 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'instance_parameters'.
[  1] 08:37:07.958 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'wizard_population_step'.
[  1] 08:37:09.402 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'wizard_population_step'.
[  1] 08:37:09.434 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'select_core_db_items'.
[  1] 08:37:10.798 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'select_core_db_items'.
[  1] 08:37:10.810 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'select_master_db_items'.
[  1] 08:37:12.496 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'select_master_db_items'.
[  1] 08:37:12.526 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'select_files'.
[  1] 08:37:13.307 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'select_files'.
[ 11] 08:37:13.344 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:plugin_poststep; Status:Queued
[  8] 08:37:13.344 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:database_master; Status:Queued
[ 15] 08:37:13.345 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:plugin_prestep; Status:Queued
[ 11] 08:37:13.346 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Initializing migration runner. RunnerKey: plugin_poststep
[  8] 08:37:13.346 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Initializing migration runner. RunnerKey: database_master
[ 15] 08:37:13.346 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Initializing migration runner. RunnerKey: plugin_prestep
[  5] 08:37:13.349 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:security; Status:Queued
[  5] 08:37:13.349 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Initializing migration runner. RunnerKey: security
[  8] 08:37:13.355 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:database_master; Status:Disabled
[  8] 08:37:13.355 WARN  [MigrationRunner] Migration is disabled. RunnerKey: database_master
[  8] 08:37:13.356 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:file_system; Status:Queued
[  8] 08:37:13.356 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Initializing migration runner. RunnerKey: file_system
[  5] 08:37:13.357 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Run pre initialization. RunnerKey: security
[ 15] 08:37:13.365 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:plugin_prestep; Status:Disabled
[ 15] 08:37:13.365 WARN  [MigrationRunner] Migration is disabled. RunnerKey: plugin_prestep
[  8] 08:37:13.365 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:file_system; Status:Disabled
[  8] 08:37:13.365 WARN  [MigrationRunner] Migration is disabled. RunnerKey: file_system
[ 15] 08:37:13.366 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:database_core; Status:Queued
[ 15] 08:37:13.366 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Initializing migration runner. RunnerKey: database_core
[ 15] 08:37:13.370 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:database_core; Status:Disabled
[ 15] 08:37:13.370 WARN  [MigrationRunner] Migration is disabled. RunnerKey: database_core
[  5] 08:37:13.374 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Pre initialization has been finished. RunnerKey: security
[  5] 08:37:13.374 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Initializing status. RunnerKey: security
[  5] 08:37:13.376 INFO  Migration runner total to process count has been updated. Runner:security; Total to process count:7
[  5] 08:37:13.377 INFO  Migration runner total unit count has been updated. Runner:security; Total count:7
[  5] 08:37:13.377 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Status has been initialized. RunnerKey: security
[  5] 08:37:13.382 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:security; Status:Skipped
[  5] 08:37:13.383 INFO  Migration runner message(security):
Migration has already finished.
[  5] 08:37:13.386 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Migration has already finished, runner skipped. RunnerKey: security
[  5] 08:37:13.387 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:configuration; Status:Queued
[  5] 08:37:13.387 INFO  [MigrationRunner] Initializing migration runner. RunnerKey: configuration
[  5] 08:37:13.392 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:configuration; Status:Disabled
[  5] 08:37:13.392 WARN  [MigrationRunner] Migration is disabled. RunnerKey: configuration
[ 11] 08:37:13.489 INFO  Migration runner status was updated. Runner:plugin_poststep; Status:Disabled
[ 11] 08:37:13.489 WARN  [MigrationRunner] Migration is disabled. RunnerKey: plugin_poststep
[  1] 08:37:13.513 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'wizard_migration_step'.
[  1] 08:37:14.177 INFO  [WizardCore] Moving to the next step. Current step key: 'wizard_migration_step'.
[  1] 08:37:14.193 INFO  [WizardCore] Moved to the next step. Current step key: 'wizard_summary_step'.
```

Comment: did you run multiple times the migration tool ?

Comment: Yes the developer did run it multiple times, the previous logs was from his recent run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue : https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/583017

As a workaround for the issue, please consider deleting the **{Express Migration Root folder}/Migration.db** file before running the migration for another source instance of the same version.

[image]

Comment: This helped me! If the migration fails the first time, it will (more or less silently) skip some steps the second time. Deleting the db file fixes this.